# locking only 1 operation?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

ive been asking myself : "why should i use lock to only one statement"...

*(IMHO - if its 1 operation only like an assignment - so there shouldnt be a problem..)?*

then i saw this :

> As a basic rule, you need to lock around accessing any writable shared
>   field. Even in the simplest case—an assignment operation on a single
>   field—you must consider synchronization. In the following class,
>   neither the Increment nor the Assign method is thread-safe:

```
class ThreadUnsafe
{
  static int _x;
  static void Increment() { _x++; }  
  static void Assign() { _x = 123; }
}
```

can you please tell me why this is not thread safe ?
ive been running many scripts in my head and couldnt find any problem...

Comment: "One operation" is usually "a few operations". Look at the disassembly when debugging to see the assembly of your code and check whether it really is one operation. If it is - you don't need to lock, obviously. Although I don't see why you'll ever need to lock one operation, logically.

Comment: `Increment` is unsafe (3 operations). `Assign` is unsafe too (1 atomic operation but you need to take care of memory synchronization through caches).

Comment: @Soohjun Increment is an atomic operation (INC dword ptr [ebp-3Ch])

Comment: @YoryeNathan That's not atomic. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: @Soohjun Interesting indeed, however the disassembly clearly shows an atomic operation.

Comment: If you don't want to put the locks around your single statement you can use the built in interlocked class to do this for you, e.g. `static void Increment() { Interlocked.Increment(ref _x);}`

Comment: @YoryeNathan You are misunderstanding what "atomic" means. It does not mean "one CPU instruction". For instance, `INC dword ptr [ebp-3Ch]` is everything *but* atomic. It essentially does a load, inc, store.

Comment: @Bob has the right approach here; this should be done with `Interlocked.Increment` and `Interlocked.Exchange`

Comment: If you know the processor instruction(s) that a line of code will eventually be compiled into, and the atomicity of those instructions. Then, you might be able to ascertain the atomicity of the line of code on a given platform. If you have explicit assurances from the producers of the compiler or framework, then you can rely on those. In all other cases you should protect your access to shared variables in whatever manner is most expedient. In this case, @Marc Gravell 's comment above.

Comment: @MarcGravell does change in value reflects in static fields ?

Comment: @Royi that isn't a `static`/non-`static` concern; you don't show how you are reading the value, so it is hard to be specific, as again it depends on volatility. For example, `Interlocked.Read` or `Thread.VolatileRead` would be examples of how to read; alternatively, there's a way to use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to perform a non-changing read.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for answering. ive read that `Threads share data if they have a common reference to the same object instance.` so if im creating an instance of my `ThreadUnSafeClass` - and making a change in its field - this change ( according to the sentence) should be reflected... no ? does each thread  then still have its own stack ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of why your example is not thread-safe. Initially, `_x = 0`. Let's say you run `Increment` and `Assign` in parallel. If the methods were thread-safe, the result should be either `100` (if increment is executed before assign) or `101` (if increment is executed after assign).

(EDIT: Note that each thread has it's own working stack!)

```
 Thread 1 (executing Increment)    Thread 2 (executing Assign 100)
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
 read _x onto stack       (= 0)
                                   put 100 on top of stack
                                   write top of stack to _x (= 100)
 increment top of stack   (= 1)
 write top of stack to _x (= 1)
```

`_x` is now `1`, which is neither `100` nor `101`.

Of course, it could be that your incrementation method is compiled into single, atomic operation by the compiler. But you cannot rely on this, unless it is specifically guaranteed by the compiler that you use.

---

If you use a lock, the following happens:

```
 Thread 1 (executing Increment)    Thread 2 (executing Assign 100)
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
 lock (success)
 read _x onto stack       (= 0)
                                   lock (lock already taken; 
                                   |     wait until Thead 1's lock is released)
 increment top of stack   (= 1)    |
 write top of stack to _x (= 1)    |
 unlock                            |
                                   +> (success)
                                   put 100 on top of stack
                                   write top of stack to _x (= 100)
                                   unlock
```

The result is now `100`. Basically, the lock ensures that two locked blocks do not overlap.

Comment: I second @RoyiNamir. Increment will result in 101, where EXPECTED to be 1 - which would basically be the problem.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I've extended the example to make it more clear. Each thread has it's own working stack.

Comment: If you use a lock you will get either 100 or 101, not 1.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, a lock will make sure that all three operations on Thread 1 are executed *without interruption from Thread 2*. I've extended my answer.

Comment: but why there should be interruption if each has its own stack ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: They are separate threads. That means that they can execute in parallel (in fact, that's the whole point of using threads).

Comment: @Heinzi but thos fields are static so the change should reflect to the other thread....

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The field is static, but the stack is local to the thread. To increment something, I need to (1) read the field to the stack, (2) update the stack, (3) write the stack value back to the field. That's how stack-based virtual machines (such as the .NET runtime) work. If the field is changed between steps (1) and (3), this change is overwritten in step (3).

Answer (score 4):

The increment operation produces this MSIL...

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Increment() cil managed
{
  // Code size       14 (0xe)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     int32 ThreadUnsafe::_x
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0007:  add
  IL_0008:  stsfld     int32 ThreadUnsafe::_x
  IL_000d:  ret
} // end of method ThreadUnsafe::Increment
```

So you can see that, even at the MSIL level, the increment is not atomic.  The JIT compiler might conceivably do something clever to turn this back into an atomic increment at the machine level, but we certainly can't depend on that.  Imagine 2 threads incrementing the same X with their "load" and "store" operations overlapped - you can see that it's possible to end up with X = X + 1 instead of X + 2.

Wrapping your increment inside a lock means they can't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think at an even lower level than the programming language.

There's no guarantee that

a) The processor will write the new value all in one go (atomic or non-atomic)

b) The value will be updated in one CPU core's cache, but not in another (lack of memory barriers)

Maybe your CPU (likely) can read and write a 32-bit integer atomically and you won't have any problems. But what happens when you're trying to read/write a 64-bit value? A 128? The value could end up in an intdeterminate state where two different threads are simultaneously modifying the same memory location, and you end up with either value a, value b, or an intermediate (and very much incorrect) value that's a mix of the two.

and many more.

Comment: Actually C# guarantees that assigns to Int32 *are* atomic.

Comment: According to the reference spec int updates are atomic, however there is the remote posibility of register caching.

Comment: @Soohjun but not necessarily via memory barriers, I think? That leaves the problem of cache coherence.

Answer (score 0):

Locking is a big messy subject, you will usually have a very hard time figuring out what goes under the hood (which core cache gets invalidated when). That's why writing efficient parallel code is a problem. Others have pointed out some potential issues even with a single assignment (and obviously with incrementing a variable). Just see all the issues with [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword: https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+volatile+concurrency&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

So, if you must do things in parallel, start by locking *a lot*, even on operations you don't think require locks. Optimize your locking only when you're seeing performance issues.